# How do I use logarithmic differentiation to find the derivative of $y=x^{\sin x}$?

Tags: calculus

This is the work I've done so far:

$\ln y=(\sin x)\ln$

$y'/y=(\cos x)\ln x+(\sin x)/x$

And I'm not sure that I've set up the problem correctly...

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: What steps did you get to derive what you have so far? Please share them in an [edit].

Comment: There is one typographical(?) error in the work you've done so far: the equation $\ln y=(\sin x)\ln$ is missing an "$x$" after the second "$\ln$".

Answer (score 2):

Let $y=x^{\sin(x)}$. then $\ln(y)=\sin(x)\ln(x)$. So: $$\frac{1}{y}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\cos(x)\ln(x)+\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$$ Then multiplying up and substituting $y=x^{\sin(x)}$ we get: $$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=x^{\sin(x)}(cos(x)\ln(x)+\frac{\sin(x)}{x})$$

Answer (score 1):

You have done! Complete and find:
$$
y'=y\left[(\cos x)\ln(x)+\frac{\sin x}x \right]=x^{\sin x}\left[(\cos x)\ln(x)+\frac{\sin x}x \right]
$$